# objective c++ operator delete

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have the following code in Xcode command line app:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<string> *pv = new vector<string>;
    vector<string> &v = *pv;


    v.push_back("juy");
    v.push_back("zxc");

    cout << v[0] << endl << v[1] << endl;

    delete pv;

    cout << v[0] << endl << v[1] << endl;

    cout << pv->operator[](0) << endl << pv->operator[](1) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, this is the output:

> ```
> juy  
> zxc  
> juy  
> zxc  
> juy  
> zxc
> ```

The question is: does operator `delete` work in objective-c++? Does it cause memory leak?

There are no errors, no exceptions, nor warnings!

Comment: My guess would be UB - because you can't tell what the deleted memory will be after `delete` has been called. But that's just my guess

Comment: what is UB? By the way, if i use 'new' again, it doesn't overwrite the memory.

Comment: UB is Undefined behaviour. When you do `new` again you probably get a new memory slot so it doesn't point to the same place as that old memory. That's why it doesn't "overwrite" it.

Comment: By the way, with the first line removed, your code is valid C++, it's nothing to do with Objective-C or Objective-C++.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has no memory leaks. However, it has [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) on the following two lines that come after the `delete`:

```
cout << v[0] << endl << v[1] << endl;

cout << pv->operator[](0) << endl << pv->operator[](1) << endl;
```

In other words, after you `delete pv`, you are not allowed dereference `pv`. If your program doesn't crash when you do, and if the memory still contains the old data, that means nothing. The behaviour is still undefined.

Comment: ok. I understand. But, how do You know that there are no memory leaks? May I have any proof? (documentation, large ios application that is known to work with mere c++, evident overwriting bits withing the same memory). I don't want to find out that the application i'm writting falls for unknown reasons.